# How to update a jsonb column of type array in postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql, jsonb

My record in Postgres DB look like

**Data Structure**

```
ID: int
codes: jsonb
```

**Example**

ID: 1
codes: "[{"op":"C","code":"1"},{"op":"C","code":"2"},{"op":"U"}]"

**Update Query**
I am looking for a way to update codes, and update `{\"op\":\"U\"}` to `{\"op\":\"U\",\"code\":\"3\"}`

Comment: Using what language?